# Redirecting console I/O: SetHandleInformation fails with invalid handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to figure out how to adapt this sample in order to [redirect the output of a console window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) to a text box inside another process.

Unfortunately, it seems that the reader will never receive any input.

Further debugging shows that the call to `SetHandleInformation` always aborts with `Error 6: Invalid Handle`. The value of `hPipeOutRd` does not look bad, it is something like 0x00000244.

This reproduces the matter:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    int result = 0;
    HANDLE hPipeOutRd = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // This end is passed to the pipe reader
    HANDLE hPipeOutWr = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; // This end is passed to the child process

    if ( result == 0 && !::CreatePipe( &hPipeOutRd, &hPipeOutWr, &sa, 4096 ) ) 
    {
        result = -1; 
        printf("Error: %u\r\n", GetLastError() ); 
    }
    if ( result == 0 && !::SetHandleInformation( &hPipeOutRd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0 ) ) // This fails with invalid handle
    {
        result = -1; 
        printf("Error: %u\r\n", GetLastError() );  
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please use the [boilerplate code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx), not that useful to re-invent it.

Comment: You pass the address of the variable les to CreatePipe because they are outputs. Utilising for SetHandleInformation the handle is input, so you pass its value. Clearly indicate by the types of the arguments and in the documentation. Read it all very closely. Consider defining STRICT. Then the compiler can find your mistakes.

Comment: gentlemien, there is a bug in Microsoft's demo code with the url posted by @antipattern as **redirect the output of a console window**  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx. It is the `boilerplate code` for a parent/child pipe i/o redirection. The parent process hangs forever. The fix is to call `CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr);` inside `ReadFromPipe` function, before entering the fur loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A HANDLE is already a pointer. You don't take its address unless it is an out parameter.

Just take the & out of your SetHandleInformation call.